# How to resolve cannot load information for github bad credentials error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, github

I'm still new in Android development. I want to share my project on GitHub but it is not working. Below is the image error it is throwing. Please i need help.

[image]

Comment: I haven't used this feature, but it looks like your window is missing the part about entering your login credentials for Github. Maybe it will reappear if you close this dialog and open it again. Or have you already uploaded it before, and are just updating it now? Maybe your login token is expired?

Answer (score 9):

I got the same issue while working on a project on Android Studio. The solution for this problem which work for me is -

1. Go to File > settings. (Or simply Ctrl+Alt+S)
2. A pop will appear on screen then navigate to Version Control > GitHub.
3. Click on login. It will redirect to GitHub Login Page.
4. After that, login into GitHub using your credentials.
5. Another way of  logging is by Token. (You can choose any of them according to your convenience.)

Answer (score 0):

In android studio
Go to **Preferences->Version control->GitHub**

Remove account having error with(-)

else **click +**
and **Add account with token->Generate token on website-> copy and paste it in studio-> Add account**

Done

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to File -> Settings...

A pop up will occur

2. Go to Version Control -> Github

Click on the account, then remove it by using the minus symbol on top of your account.

3. Click add account, it will redirect you. You can now login and generate a token and when doing that don't use the same token name you used before. Once its been generate you can go back to your Android Studio and paste it.

This worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

1 -> Press ctrl+alt+s

2 -> Version control

3 -> GitHub

4 -> Add your account by clicking on the "+" button

5 -> Generate a Token and paste it into the token field in Android Studio.[image]